# Setting checkbox attribute vs .click() event

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am creating a classic fake checkbox so I have freedom to style.
I can either create an if checked, or just trigger a click on the sibling input.
The ifChecked only worked for the first time the event was triggered for some reason.
This checks the box visually but doesn't create checked="checked"
is `checkbox.click();` a viable option (even though there's no checked="checked")

The HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="fcb1" name="receive_info"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="receive_info">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-10">
lorem
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <div class="fcb2" name="tos"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tos" >
</div>
```

Here is the JS

```
$('div[class^="fcb"]').click(function(){

$(this).toggleClass("checked");
var checkbox = $(this).siblings("input");
checkbox.click();


    });
```

Here's using Prop:

```
    $('div[class^="fcb"]').click(
        function(){

$(this).toggleClass("checked");
var checkbox = $(this).siblings("input");
/*checkbox.click();*/
var isChecked = checkbox.is(':checked');
if (isChecked){
    console.log('event');
        checkbox.prop('checked', "");
    } else {
        checkbox.prop('checked', 'checked'); 
    }
    });
```

Comment: Why not show us how you checked the checkbox, you probably used `attr` when you should be using `prop`

Comment: @adeneo here - I added. I tried both but read that .prop is better. I vaguely recall a while ago having the same problem and finding out that even if it doesn't show checked="checked" in the DOM - it's still checked. Is that the case?

Comment: It's supposed to be a boolean, as `checkbox.prop('checked', true);`, not a string.

Comment: You could use a label with the for attribute so you don't need js - just css3 - [example](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953)